# After installing oh-my-zsh on El Capitan, I get this error: .zshrc:source:61:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, path, osx-elcapitan, atom-editor, oh-my-zsh

I've been using oh-my-zsh for a while and really like it. But the computer I normally used needed to be repaired, so I am borrowing my employer's MacBook. I am mostly unfamiliar with Macbooks, which is what I am blaming for the difficulty I am having. So here is the deal:

I used Homebrew to install oh-my-zsh and git. If I put `$PATH` in terminal or zsh(not really sure anymore to be honest) my error message is as follows:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If I type `zsh` my error is: `/Users/Reed/.zshrc:source:61: no such file or directory: /Users/Reed/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh`

`zsh --version` is `zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0)`
 
My `.zshrc` file is as follows:

```
export ZSH=/Users/Reed/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="bullet-train"
plugins=(git bundler osx rake ruby rails gem heroku atom)
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help you can give me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://coderwall.com/p/0o64yq/rbenv-issues-when-switching-to-zsh
if you using rbenv, you should move your rbenv initialization to ~/.zshenv as in

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._